# On the derivation of space-time interval

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, metric-tensor

The introduction to GR of Bernard Schutz, writes de space-time interval like this

$\Delta\bar{s}^{2}=M_{\alpha\,\beta}(\Delta x^{\alpha})(\Delta x^{\beta})$

$\Delta\bar{s}^2$ is the space-time interval in the moving frame

$\Delta x^{\alpha}$ is the component in the non-moving frame.

I understand that part, but the weird think comes when he says: "Note that we can suppose that $M_{\alpha\,\beta}=M_{\beta\,\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$, since only the sum $M_{\alpha\,\beta}+M_{\beta\,\alpha}$ ever appears in the previous Eq. when $\alpha\neq \beta$"

I just can't get my head around that. I just don't see how the fact that you can have something like $(M_{\alpha\,\beta}+M_{\beta\,\alpha})(\Delta x^{\alpha})(\Delta x^{\beta})$ appears in the sum you can suppose $M_{\alpha\,\beta}=M_{\beta\,\alpha}$  for me it just come of nowhere. I know it should be like this because $M$ will become the metric tensor for flat space time, but the statement...

Comment: If there are no other reasons to consider the $M_{\alpha\beta}$ separately, then it makes sense to redefine $\tilde{M}_{\alpha\beta} = (M_{\alpha\beta} + M_{\beta\alpha})/2$, and eventually relabel $\tilde{M}_{\alpha\beta} \rightarrow M_{\alpha\beta}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without making any assumption about the metric, we will have
$$
ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu = \frac{1}{2} ( g_{\mu\nu} + g_{\nu\mu} ) dx^\mu dx^\nu
$$
Now define a new metric
$$
{\tilde g}_{\mu\nu} =  \frac{1}{2} ( g_{\mu\nu} + g_{\nu\mu} ) \qquad \implies \qquad ds^2 = {\tilde g}_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu 
$$
This new metric is symmetric, ${\tilde g}_{\mu\nu} = {\tilde g}_{\nu\mu}$.

All computations in SR/GR depend only on the line-element. But since the line element takes the same form irrespective of which metric $g$ or ${\tilde g}$ is used, we are free to choose whichever one we want.

It is convenient to choose the symmetric matrix.

Another way to think about this is to note that $g$ is a matrix. All matrices can be decomposed into a symmetry part $g^S$ and an antisymmetric part $g^A$. The line element is
$$
ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu = (g^S_{\mu\nu} + g^A_{\mu\nu} ) dx^\mu dx^\nu =  g^S_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu ~. 
$$
Thus, only the symmetric part of the matrix $g$ appears in the line element. The antisymmetric part of the metric drops out of all calculations in SR/GR and absolutely no physical answer depends on it. Therefore, we might as well set it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the summation over the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you will find terms that look like:
$$
M_{12}\Delta x^1\Delta x² \quad + \quad M_{21}\Delta x² \Delta x^1
$$
And, since you can interchange the $\Delta x^1$ and $\Delta x²$ then you can combine the two terms of $M$ into a subexpression such as:
$$
(M_{12} \,+\,M_{21})\Delta x^1\Delta x^2
$$

Comment: Yep, thanks I did write that. How are you assuming $M_{a\,b}=M_{b\,a}$?

Comment: Metric tensors are symmetric.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor), at the bottom of the introduction section.

Comment: @Javier. If they are different it makes no difference. The only thing you can ever measure is the sum of the two, so the two separately mean nothing. In science if it has no effect it makes no difference.